# Navigate Urls by div click

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"
  onclick="document.getElementById('<%=fav1.ClientID%>').click()" class="grid">
//some content
<asp:LinkButton id="fav1" runat="server" visible="false"
PostBackurl="~/someurl.aspx" />
</div>
```

The div is clickable and I would like it to navigate to the target page on click, but thats not happening. 
There are 10 such divs on page and the postbackurl for all linkbuttons are added dynamically.
(I just hardcoded here to test).

Also added, the onclick property for the button, but it doesnt fire the server event too. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="$(document.getElementById('<%=fav1.ClientID%>')).click()"
```

full code:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="$(document.getElementById('<%=fav1.ClientID%>')).click()" class="grid">
//some content
<asp:LinkButton id="fav1" runat="server" visible="false"
PostBackurl="~/someurl.aspx" />
</div>
```

Comment: could you please post the output of your example, i.e. exactly the onclick and the <a> tag?

Comment: <div id="div1" runat="server"
  onclick="$(document.getElementById('<%=fav1.ClientID%>')).click()" class="grid"> <asp:LinkButton id="fav1" runat="server" visible="false"
PostBackurl="~/denied.aspx" /></div>

Comment: my dear, the output rendered html, i.e. run it in a browser and look at the page source

Comment: onclick="$(document.getElementById(&#39;&lt;%=fav1.ClientID%>&#39;)).click()"> <a id="contentplaveholder1_fav1" href="javascript:_doPostBack(&#39;ct100$contentplaceholder1$fav1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"></a>

Comment: well as you can see your client id in the onclick is not rendered right. i think its because you have a runat=server on the div, can you remove it and check again?

Comment: nope. - `onclick="$document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder_fav1')).click()"`

Comment: my friend you have again mistakes in your code ($document, without "("), try again the full code i posted for you